# Enable / disable button when row is tapped

Tags: uitableview, swift

I would like to enable my button for segue if minimum one row in `tableView` is selected. Also the button should be disabled if no row is selected / marked.

At the moment I have this code and Im only able to enable it but I can not disable it anymore:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    var whatIsSelected: String = ""

    // Get Cell Label
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
    let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as UITableViewCell!

    whatIsSelected = currentCell.textLabel!.text!

    // Unmark selected
    if (currentCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark) {
        currentCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
    // Mark selected category
    } else {
        currentCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
    }`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE:

Replaced my answer. This is a working prototype ViewController:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UITableViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var testButton: UIButton!
  let testData = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Thirty two :)"]

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
    testButton.enabled = false
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as UITableViewCell!
    currentCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
    testButton.enabled = true
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as UITableViewCell!
    currentCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
    let selectedRows = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows() as? [NSIndexPath]
    if selectedRows == nil {
      testButton.enabled = false
    }
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return testData.count
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let data = testData[indexPath.row]
    let cell =  UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier: "CELL")
    cell.textLabel?.text = data
    return cell
  }
}
```

Comment: What I dont get 100% is: when I now mark two rows and unmark one of the rows, it will disable me the button insted to let the button active till I unselect the last row...

Comment: I could be a logic vs visual thing? Are you allowing multiple selection? `allowsMultipleSelection` in code or Storyboard?

Comment: At the end I paln to save the selected rows into a plist and load them afther the user have done once the "initial-setup"    Im a beginner in swift and at the moment I dont know anything about the multipleSection. What I've now tried is: I've declared a global countRows as Int and count them ceach time a row is taped (increase) and each time is taped for unmark ( decrease) and deactivate the button when countRows is equal 0. This works so far. What do you think about this solution?

Comment: I open Xcode over here, and made a working example. I think this would help. Will replace my answer.

Comment: If you just want to store the selected indexes/ids for some setting to rember, I would recommend checking out NSDefaults  -https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html. Good way to persist simple data.

Comment: Sorry Mikael here is clearly standing its not allowed to post "thank you" or +1 and stuff like this. But I have to say thank you very much! Your solution works and I appreciate it!